# gem execution is inordinately slow

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a custom CLI gem ('pm') built using thor which runs in acceptable time on the dev system but is extraordinarily slow on the production system and I don't understand why.

The specs, results of time & profiling on both systems are:

```
development system          production system
------------------          -----------------
real    0m6.859s            real    0m53.405s
user    0m6.464s            user    0m52.334s
sys     0m0.364s            sys     0m0.840s

prod system: Linux grumples 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

dev system: Linux cb-8 4.2.0-36-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 15:49:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

MRI ruby 2.2.2

Profiling produces:

dev system

   %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
  9.82     0.55      0.55     1481     0.37    15.83  Kernel#require
  4.46     0.80      0.25     5376     0.05     0.12  Erubis::TinyEruby#convert
  4.11     1.03      0.23     8682     0.03     0.07  Neo4j::Shared::TypecastedAttributes#_attribute_typecaster
  3.39     1.22      0.19     7831     0.02     0.02  Regexp#match
  3.39     1.41      0.19    20519     0.01     0.03  Domainatrix::DomainParser#read_dat_file
  3.04     1.58      0.17    15480     0.01     0.03  MIME::Type.simplify_matchdata
  3.04     1.75      0.17     6386     0.03     0.24  Array#map
  1.96     1.86      0.11     8682     0.01     0.11  Neo4j::Shared::TypecastedAttributes#attribute
  1.96     1.97      0.11    14529     0.01     0.40  Array#each
  1.96     2.08      0.11    78487     0.00     0.00  Hash#[]
  1.79     2.18      0.10     9874     0.01     0.24  Neo4j::Shared::Attributes#attributes_map
  1.79     2.28      0.10      154     0.65     1.30  Hash#each


prodn system

  %   cumulative   self              self     total
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name
 40.63     1.93      1.93    90324     0.02     0.08  Gem::Dependency#matching_specs
 15.16     2.65      0.72     5122     0.14     4.15  Array#each
  7.79     3.02      0.37     3252     0.11     0.20  Gem::Version#<=>
  4.21     3.22      0.20    10590     0.02     0.04  Gem::Specification#runtime_dependencies
  3.58     3.39      0.17    87738     0.00     0.00  String#===
  2.53     3.51      0.12    87942     0.00     0.00  Gem::StubSpecification#name
  2.53     3.63      0.12     3966     0.03     0.06  Gem::Version#bump
  2.32     3.74      0.11     4304     0.03     0.03  Kernel#initialize_dup
  1.68     3.82      0.08     1583     0.05     0.54  nil#
  1.47     3.89      0.07     2610     0.03     0.07  Array#any?
  1.26     3.95      0.06     3252     0.02     0.06  Gem::Version#version
  1.05     4.00      0.05    17117     0.00     0.00  Module#===
  1.05     4.05      0.05     2023     0.02     0.08  Gem::BasicSpecification#contains_requirable_file?
```

40% of its time in `Gem::Dependency#matching_specs` seems like a lot of something going on that must be optimisable.

I would appreciate any guidance on how to further investigate the reason the production version is so slow.

Regards

**Addendum 1**

The .gemrc file is identical on both prodn & dev systems

```
~/.gemrc

---
:backtrace: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources:
- https://rubygems.org
- http://[private gem server]
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
gem: '--no-document --no-ri'
```

There is no /etc/gemrc on either system

**Addendum 2**

gem env's from both dev & prodn systems

production system

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/ql/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/ql/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ql/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/ql/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
     - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org", "http://[private gem server]"]
     - "gem" => "--no-document --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org
     - http://[private gem server]
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/ql/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
     - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bin
     - /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin
     - /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
```

development system

```
gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.8
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.2 (2015-04-13 patchlevel 95) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.2.2
     - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - :sources => ["https://rubygems.org", "http://[private gem server]/"]
     - "gem" => "--no-document"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org
     - http://[private gem server]/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /home/cb/.gem/ruby/2.2.2/bin
     - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bin
     - /home/cb/.rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
     - .
     - bin
```

**Addendum 3**
`top` summary for production server

```
top - 20:11:26 up 1 day,  1:18,  1 user,  load average: 0.02, 0.04, 0.05
Tasks:  94 total,   2 running,  92 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.3 us,  0.2 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   4048288 total,  2797220 used,  1251068 free,   369612 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.   922420 cached Mem
```

Not much happening on production @ mo. Dev system is working much harder. System isn't incurring any swapping penalty @ mo either.

Removing the trailing slash on the private gem server url has no impact on execution time.

**Addendum 4**
Tested private gem on a 16GB mem DO droplet and performance issues went away. Both servers built with the same Ansible playbook.

Comment: Is there a `~/.gemrc` file on your prod host?  If so, please post it.

Comment: Or possibly it would be `/etc/gemrc`.

Comment: see addendum above re .gemrc

Comment: Are there any differences between the .gemrc in the 2 hosts, especially the `sources`?

Comment: the differences are: sources on the dev system .gemrc has a trailing slash on the private gem server url and it does not have a '--no-ri' option

Comment: I've added a `gem env` output as **Addendum 2** above from both systems

Comment: The --no-ri option should make gem installing faster, so that's not a problem.  I don't think the trailing slash does anything but you could try removing it on the dev system just to test it.  But I think it's something else.  Is the CPU heavily loaded on the prod server?  Or is memory limited to the point that swapping is happening?

Comment: See addendum 3 for more info

Comment: Is it just this Ruby process that's slow on that host?  I've seen dramatic slowdowns on Linux hosts when ipv6 is enabled.  Is it a shared host, by any chance?  I've been having abysmal performance lately on my Bluehost shared host.

Comment: Its on a DigitalOcean VPS (droplet) & ipv6 is not enabled.
It doesn't look like the issue extends to other ruby processes which are all rails based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution was found by switching to another vps with increased memory from 4Gb to 16Gb (even though swap space was unused in both cases).
Both systems built with the same Ansible playbook (same versions of all components).
Performance issues evaporated and not entirely sure why. But that'll do.